# Does CocoaPods prevent double clicks on XCode project files?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am considering using CocoaPods on an existing iOS project.
However I got confused when I read the [installation instructions](http://cocoapods.org/), which say:

> Make sure to always open the Xcode workspace instead of the project
>   file when building your project:
>       $ open App.xcworkspace

I have no idea what they want to tell me with that. I know there is a .xworkspace file within the .xcodeproj bundle.

But does that mean I can never again simple double click on my .xcodeproj file? Can I no longer open the project from the XCode recent items menu? And do I always need to open it from Terminal?

The concept of CocoaPods sounds interesting, but I don't want to mess with XCodes internal project structure...

Comment: You just need to double click on workspace if you use cocoa pods to run your project in your projects folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workspace is like a step up from a project. It can contain several projects. When you install Cocoapods on your project, it creates a workspace which contains your original project and a new Pods project which contains the code from the pods you are using.

It also creates dependencies between your project and the pods project (since your project needs the pods project to be built before you can build your own, it has to look for the headers, etc.). Because of this, if you subsequently open the project file instead of the workspace file, it will fail to build because it doesn't have the right information about the Pods.

The change doesn't really affect anything about the way you work - just double-click the workspace file instead of the project file, and the workspace will subsequently show up in your recent items list.

You don't need to open it from the terminal, that guide is just there because you would have installed the pods from the command line, so it is a convenience to then open the workspace file immediately from there.

Comment: Ah I see. CocoaPods CREATES that workspace files. I thought I would need to open that workspace file from within the .xcodeproj bundle. Thanks for your explanation.